TestNG not showing in run configurations
TestNG is not showing in run configurations. Steps I took :

Create a new maven project

Adding testng dependency in the pom.xml file.

Installing Testng  plugin from eclipse marketplace.

Keeping my test class in src/test/java/tests
"tests" is the package which contains Testclass.java


Detailed Screen-cast : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WXCfvuXA1YBwp6H02PJH_qVvNY8u2Gpt/view?usp=sharing
Issue:
package tests;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Testclass {

    @Test
    public void foo() {

    }

}

The above code is not showing option to run it as "Testng" project. Please help as everything was working fine few days ago. I am worried.

First question: Which Maven version do you use? Which JDK Version do you use? Also try to execute mvn test on the console?

Hye! @kh
https://prnt.sc/kS8F_-VF1I4A

You are using ancient old plugin versions and also having compiler issues...
